# Divide members into multiple teams without overlap

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to separate people from a pool into several smaller groups. The group-size should always remain the same. People can be part of several groups - but no two people can be part of more than one group.

```
members = [A,B,C,D,E]

group1 = [A,B,C]
group2 = [A,D,E]
```

There aren't anymore valid groups possible.
`A` can't be part of any more groups. `B` can't be in a group with `C` anymore (because they're already members of `group1`. `B` can be in a group with `D`, however `E` cannot be part of that group, because it can't be in a group with `E` - since they're both already in `group2`.

So my question is, is there an algorithm where I can figure out all the possible team combinations for every members-size and group-size?

Comment: How about: `group1 = [A,B,C]`, `group2 = [B,D,E]`? You need all varations or just 1 random one that fits requirements?

Comment: @RazorHail, when you said *There aren't anymore valid groups possible* you meant that there cannot be a `group3`  provided that  sizeof(group)=3, right? because **ulou** is right that there are many other variations that meet your constrains with sizeof(group)=3

Comment: @ulou Just a random one. This obviously is very easy to do with group-size 3 and a total of 5 members. But what if there were 9 members, etc.

Comment: Progamming language? Or are you looking for pseudo code e.g. in JS?

Comment: @AmoRobb yes, correct. If the group-size is 3 and there are 5 total members. There are only 2 possible teams at the same time

Comment: @ulou sure pseudocode (or any other language) is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem and wanted to share it with everybody

First, I need this helper-function that checks if any of the members of a current team have already been part of a previous team before:

```
def part_of_prev_teams(current_team):
    for member_i in range(0, len(current_team)):
        for member_j in range(member_i, len(current_team)):
            for team in teams:
                if member_i != member_j:
                    if current_team[member_i] in team and current_team[member_j] in team:
                        return True
```

The actual function looks like this:

```
pool = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
team_size = 3
teams = []

for member_i in range(0, len(pool)-1):              # iterate every member
    current_team = [pool[member_i]]                 # add the current member to current team
    for member_j in range(member_i, len(pool)):
        if len(current_team) >= team_size:          # team full
            break
        if pool[member_j] in current_team:          # member_i == member_j
            pass
        else:
            current_team.append(pool[member_j])     # add current member into the current_team
            if len(current_team) > 1:               # team has at least 2 members
                if part_of_prev_teams(current_team):# check for conflicts
                    current_team.pop()              # member was incorrectly added. remove it again
    if len(current_team) == team_size:              # team size has been reached. Finalize result
        print(current_team)
        teams.append(current_team)
```

For 9 members and a team-size of 3, this is what the result looks like:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['B', 'D', 'E']
['C', 'D', 'F']
['D', 'G', 'H']
['E', 'F', 'G']
['F', 'H', 'I']
```

Additionally, I've written this print-function to count the membership count of every member:

```
def print_memberships(teams):
    for member in pool:
        member_count = 0
        for team in teams:
            member_count += team.count(member)
        print(member + ": " + str(member_count))
```

Which prints the following result:

memberships:

```
A: 1
B: 2
C: 2
D: 3
E: 2
F: 3
G: 2
H: 2
I: 1
```

So, these are very "unfair" results. I was expecting every member to be part of an equal amount of teams, which isn't the case.

So then I went back to the pool-array and added another A/I (because it was in the least number of teams) and got much better results:

```
pool = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "A"]  # 2x "A" in list

['A', 'B', 'C']
['B', 'D', 'E']
['C', 'D', 'F']
['D', 'G', 'H']
['E', 'F', 'G']
['F', 'H', 'I']
['G', 'I', 'A']

memberships:
A: 2
B: 2
C: 2
D: 3
E: 2
F: 3
G: 3
H: 2
I: 2
A: 2
I: 2
```